# Will a make up air vent cause an issue in the winter?

Tags: hvac, fireplace, ventilation, ducts

I recently installed a gas range and I will soon be installing a 300cfm range hood. Since I primarily burn wood in the winter for heat and I don't want any back-drafting issues, I am planning on installing a make up air vent in my cold air return ducting (I have a gas furnace I use as a back up for heat). However, I have a few concerns with the make up air. It gets cold where I live (think sub-zero) during the winter. Will the make up air bring noticeably cold air in through the vents? My concern is that it will make some of the rooms cold in the winter by counteracting the wood stove's heat.

Comment: Does the wood burning system have it's own source of combustion air, or is it pulling from the conditioned space in the home? How old is the home, and have there been any modifications to the home to seal it up tighter than when it was built?

Comment: @Tester101 It is pulling air from the conditioned space. The home is about 20 years old. There haven't been any modifications to my knowledge. We recently had a bad backdraft problem when the outside temperature suddenly rose higher than the interior temperature. The smoke would not go up the flue at all and it started leaking through the door and even the piping seams.

Comment: Was the wood burning appliance installed when the home was built, or was it added later?

Comment: @Tester101 I believe it was installed when the home was built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The make up air would only be pulling fresh air in when your furnace is running unless you add a small powered duct. If you use the furnace to circulate the house air without the heat on yes it will be cooler but make up air is a good idea especially in winter when the house is closed up tight.